# Magento SOAP API deletes the products in cart upon setting user address (CE 1.7)

Tags: magento-1.7, soap

'm working on an ECommerce mobile app which consumes magento's SOAP API for fetching products, adding them to cart and checkout. The checkout used to work fine, however it's giving me troubles now. When I set cart_customer.addresses for checkout, my products get deleted from the shopping cart.

This is a strange problem as cart_customer.addresses has nothing to do with products in cart. Please help me with this. We are using the default SOAP API v1.0 and no customizations have been made to it.

Here's my code to set addresses.

```
$addressBill["mode"] = "billing";
$addressShip["mode"] = "shipping";
$addresses = array($addressBill, $addressShip);

$setCustomer = array('cart_customer.set', array($cart, $customer));
$setAddress = array('cart_customer.addresses', array($cart, $addresses));
$shipping = array('cart_shipping.list', $cart);
$payment = array('cart_payment.list', $cart);
$calls = array($setCustomer, $setAddress, $shipping, $payment);
try {
    $result = $client->multicall($session, $calls);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die (json_encode(array("code"=>"104", "error"=>"Could not place order"))); 
}
```